# How do I get the output columns of ns/bs into a data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table, splines

I have a `data.table` of features for example:

```
library(data.table)
m = data.table(x1=rnorm(10),x2=rnorm(10))
```

Normally if I wanted a natural spline basis expansion for one of the features in `lm` I could do something like:

```
library(splines)
m[,lm(x2 ~ ns(x1,df=4))]
```

But if all I want is to add the spline basis columns to my data.frame for later the following does not work:

```
m[,c('a','b','c','d') := ns(x1,df=4)]
```

Is there an elegant way to assign them? Without manually extracting columns like this:

```
foo = ns(m$x1,df=4)
m[,a:=foo[1,]] #etc
```

Comment: Try `m[,c('a','b','c','d') := as.data.table(ns(x1,df=4))]`

Comment: @Frank, but what happened to `setDT`??

Comment: @DavidArenburg `setDT` works well on a `list` not a `matrix`, last I checked :)

Comment: @Frank your suggestion works, thanks! I had tried as.matrix and that didn't work.

Comment: Oh, whatever, had to put some `setDT` pun here.